# Alphanumeric string increment using for loop

Tags: php

I have a two variable one is string contains number and another one is number,
I want increase the numeric part of string upto second number.

```
$n ='sh500';
$c = 3; 
for($i=$n;$i<$c;$i++)
echo $i.'<br>';
```

I want output like:

```
sh500
sh501
sh502
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `$n++` where `$n = 'sh500'`. [It works.](http://codepad.org/vzPSfcPy)

```
$n ='sh500';
$c = 3; 
for($i = 0;$i < $c;$i++) {
    echo $n++.'<br>';
}
```

Will output

```
sh500 <br>
sh501 <br>
sh502 <br>
```

It even works when ending with a alphanumeric character, because php converts it to the ASCII value of the character and adds one so `a` will become `b` and so on. But that's out of the scope of the question :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$x="sh500";
$x = substr($x,0,2) . (substr($x,2) + 1);

echo $x;
```

echoes `sh501` (works for any string having a number from 3rd character)

Answer (score 1):

```
$n = 'sh';
for($i = 500; $i < 503; $i++) {
    echo "$n$i\n";
}
```

Comment: $n ='sh500'; is not fixed,it change dynamicaly like $n ='dewd94' or $n='rew231' etc.

Comment: then place this code in function and just pass the dynamic number to the function and use it to initialize `$i` (can also pass the upper limit then)

Comment: @er_Rajendraa: then you can start out by splitting the text from the numeric part using ``preg_match``.

Answer (score 0):

```
$n="sh50";
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
$j=$n.$i;

echo $j."<br>";
}
```

it echo:
sh500
sh501
sh502
sh503
sh504
sh505
sh506
sh507
sh508
sh509

Answer (score 0):

```
$n = 'sh500';
$c = 3;
$sh = substr($n,0,2); // will be "sh"
$number = substr($n,2,5) + 1; // will be "500"
for($i = $number; $i < 504; $i++) {
 echo $sh.$i."\n";
}
```

Live demo: [Here](http://codepad.org/KVaJ6mYz)

Answer (score 0):

```
$x = "sh500";
$s = substr($x, 0, 2);
$n = substr($x, 2);

$c = 3; 
for ($i = $n; $i < ($n + $c); $i++)
{
    echo $s.$i.'<br>';
}
```

**OR** another simple way is...

```
$n ='sh500';
$c = 3; 
for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
    echo $n++."<br>";
}
```

**Output**

```
sh500
sh501
sh502
```

Answer (score 0):

if it is always a string of length 2 else use preg_match to find the first occurrence of a number.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

```
$number = intval(substr($n, 2));
$number++;

echo substr($n, 0, 2) . $number;
```