# PHP Increase string value

Tags: php

I faced with some issue to increase the vale of the string, for example:

```
$string = "someString_1";
```

I need value `somestring_2`. Ofcourse I can use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038695/alphanumeric-string-increment-using-for-loop).
But was trying to find another way and as a result I found that it will be enought make $string++ in my case;

```
$string++;
echo $string; //someString_2
```

It was great that I have only 1 string of code. BUT:
Queston, `is this correct way, or is there more better variants?`(in condition that my string allways will have integer at the end)

And why it does not work when integer at the first position. For example if we make:

`echo '1string' + '2string';`// result 3. This is how PHP work with string when we want make some mathemetic operations

Comment: This will have some problems when you have `$string = "someString_9"; $string++; echo $string;`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885440/increment-behavior-on-strings-php-easter-egg -- incrementing numeric strings works, but is not proper code. RegEx is the better solution

Comment: @Mark Baker. Eh , I just thing about it. I should set 09 it that case to get 10, not good idea(

Comment: But if you set `someString_09`, what will happen when you reach `someString_99`.... string incrementing is extremely useful in the right circumstances, but does have its limitations

Comment: Agree totaly, in project range will be 0-9, but who knows what will be later..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this regular expression. This snippet works and it gave me result as `someString_2`

```
 $string = "someString_1";
 function increment($matches) {
   return ++$matches[1];
 }

echo $string =  preg_replace_callback( "|(\d+)|", "increment", $string);
```

Comment: Perhaps this response could be improved by using an anonymous function. I don't like to create a function and then call it from one place only (because later maybe I remove the preg_replace_callback() and forget the function and then somebody else wonders why the increment function exists).

Answer (score 2):

There is an explanation on php.net http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

PHP follows Perl's convention when dealing with arithmetic operations on character variables and not C's. For example, in PHP and Perl $a = 'Z'; $a++; turns $a into 'AA', while in C a = 'Z'; a++; turns a into '[' (ASCII value of 'Z' is 90, ASCII value of '[' is 91). Note that character variables can be incremented but not decremented and even so only plain ASCII alphabets and digits (a-z, A-Z and 0-9) are supported. Incrementing/decrementing other character variables has no effect, the original string is unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution probably works, but imagine, that someone has to modify your code some time later. Would you guess (without any research) what it does, if you saw `$string++` somewhere? Even if it works, it's much better in my opinion, to create a function which does what you need, and has a name, which makes it clear, what it does.